# Google Analytics page url displayed wrong

Tags: google-analytics

In one of my client's sites in Google Analytics, under Site Content > All Pages, all the page urls are showing incorrectly, with the domain name placed after the page url.

Normally the homepage is displayed as  /

in this case the homepage is displayed as:

/www.domain.com

and all other pages are the same, such as:

/shopping-cart/www.domain.com

does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at the filter for the account. it looks like there might be a custom filter that is taking the hostname and appending after the page URI

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a Filter was created to show the full domain name, but the variables for *Hostname*, **$A1**, and *Request URI*, **$B1**, got switched around.

Here is a screenshot of the filter I use with the variables underlined.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue and saw that I had the Default URL setting set to our domain:
[screencapture of default url field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh6au.png)

This field is under View Settings. We had entered the domain in this field and it was appending it to pages because this field is intended for "index.html" paths.